# What is cooks-kim algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was reading about sorting of presorted list in which few numbers are unsorted, someone said that cooks-kim algorithm is best for such cases, I googled about it but no relevant links.

Please let me know if anyone knows about it

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one [research paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359024.359026) of them... You can view it if you have ACM account

Answer (score 4):

Kurtis R Cook, Do Jin Kim, the paper you want is called "Best sorting algorithm for nearly sorted list", can be found in *Communications of the ACM,
23:620–624, 1980.*

Can't find anywhere to download it from, the publisher keeps vigilant, [$15 from ACM](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359024.359026) themselves.

To answer your question, it's a combination of an insertion sort and a quick sort, optimised for reordering mostly ordered data.  ie. bringing a previously sorted list back in to a sorted form after some alterations.